# Ruby select method in Has Many Through Association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Can you explain What the following method does and how it works? I have tried to understand it researching for several hours, but I couldn't figure it out yet.

```
  def self.tag_counts
    Tag.select("tags.name, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
  end
```

What I understand is the ruby method 'select' usually takes a block, not like the one used in this method. The self.tag_counts method is in the event model of my application as follows.

**models/event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :organizers, class_name: "User"
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

  def all_tags
    tags.map(&:name).join(",")
  end

  def all_tags=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end

  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).events
  end

  def self.tag_counts
    Tag.select("tags.name, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
  end
end
```

**models/tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :events, through: :taggings
end
```

**models/tagging.rb**

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ActiveRecord query of the database.  It's returning the list of tags with name and number of taggings.  It looks like the input data for a tag cloud or a tag leaderboard.

This will produce something like the following SQL statement:

```
   SELECT tag.name, count(taggings.tag_id) as count
     FROM tags
LEFT JOIN taggings ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
 GROUP BY taggings.tag_id
```

When you think of the Ruby select method, you may be thinking of the Array#select method, which is essentially a filter for arrays.  The ActiveRecord select method is a database query refinement tool.  You can read more about it in the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) guide in the [Selecting Specific Fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) section.

Comment: So the select method used in the case is not the array method but the ActiveRecord select method?

Comment: That's correct.  It's just specifying that the columns returned in the query are the tag name and the count of taggings on each tag.

Comment: You guessed right. The example is exactly the input data for a tag cloud.

Comment: @ThePac Yep, I've written almost exactly that query before.  :D

Comment: @Gaskill Of course!! Really helpful. I will do it as soon as I finish learning this part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111851/discussion-between-the-pac-and-michael-gaskill).